# Exception caught Method not found: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiationResponse on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, signalr

The code seems to work with **UWP** in **Xamarin.Forms** but when i try this with **iOS** i get the following error

> Exception caught Method not found:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiationResponse
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiateProtocol.ParseResponse

Is there something that needs to be updated in **iOS** for this to work?

I am using **Microsoft.AspNetcore.SignalrClient v 5.0.4**.

This was working in previous versions, any ideas?

Comment: What is the ios version for your device? It supports iOS apps using Xamarin.iOS 11.14.0.4 and later. You could check the MS docs for more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: we are using ios 14.1 for testing.  any other ideas

Comment: I just tried this with the sample github signalr tests, and i get the same error Method not found: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiationResponse Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiateProtocol.ParseResponse(System.ReadOnlySpan`1<byte>)

Comment: @Curtis-C are these links of any use: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10592 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29762 ? They seem to be similar issues.

Answer (score 12):

You might find a workaround here:

https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20805#issuecomment-841321110

Basically the solution is modifying the iOS.csproj file to include

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="System.Buffers">
      <Version>4.5.1</Version>
      <IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets>      
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory">
      <Version>4.5.4</Version>
      <IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets>      
    </PackageReference>
```

as in [this commit](https://github.com/peppy/osu/commit/7763e1dbe130233a61493ddf1cfacab1be0f3063#diff-a29ffd1e51d41ad45c7e5efff03df57f76efb2a2ce16f9473bb8a70da61d16c2)

[image]

Comment: This worked for me.  One thing to note, I didn't read carefully enough, it's important to note, the ```<IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets>``` is key.  I read the post and was like, "oh just add nuget packages for memory and buffers", but nowhat you are really doing is explicitly excluding their resources.  so don't just add the nuget packages, you really have to edit the csproj file and exclude the assets.

Comment: I don't really like such workarounds but it works, thanks
I hope Microsoft will fix it to get it work out of the box

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the iOS.proj does not work for everyone. The issue is actually VS2022 related.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Disable XAML hot reload in VS2022 (Debug > Options > XAML Hot Reload > Disable Hot Reload for Xamarin.Forms)
2. Use VS2019

Last update on the issue (November 2021) from MSFT:

> In Visual Studio 2019, XAML Hot Reload used “BinaryFormatter” for
> serialization and deserialization of messages between the Hot Reload
> agent, and the IDE. For VS 2022, we deprecated that (as it wouldn’t
> work with .NET 6 and also BinaryFormatter has issues of its own) and
> moved to Protobuf. For that to work, we load additional dependencies
> to support it, such as System.Memory and System.Buffers if it wasn’t
> already loaded by the application. This seems to be the root of the
> problem. Depending on other dependencies loaded, it can conflict and
> cause issues like this one.
>
> We’re researching how to handle this.

Comment: They give no indication that they're using Visual Studio 2022, and that's by no means a guarantee since Visual Studio 2022 was in a preview state when this was posted. As a result, it's not clear (to me) that this is what caused the OP's problem—though it may well be useful to people having this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in the IOS .csproj, some lib targeted netstandard2.1 instead of 2.0:

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

Switching back to netstandard2.0 worked for me. (My Common library is a netstandard2.0)

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```